# ImageView changes ScaleType

Tags: java, android, scaletype

I try to solve a problem since days now.
I have a dialog which is center in both dimensions. At the top of the dialog there is an imageview. Now when the content of the dialog changes, the following happens:
A TextView which line count reaches 2 because of the content causes that the dialog resizes itself because of the property: "wrap_content". Now the dialog moves a bit up to be centered again.

In this moment my Imageview scales itself awkward. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Thank you all! You all do a great work

Comment: does any one have an idea? :/